# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server - Googling for 30 minutes. Don't know what to do

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'll call myself stupid and lazy (even though I've been searching for 45 minutes) in advance, because I know this is a commonly asked question.

I downloaded XAMPP a few months ago. Today I'm trying to log into phpMyAdmin as root, but I get the error message in my title.

I went to the config.inc.php file and changed the root password from just '' to see if it would help, but it didn't.

I also changed my port number in the Apache (httpd.conf) file multiple times but that didn't help either.

Comment: You can reinstall your XAMPP

Comment: Every source I saw online with people asking this question said that re-installing didn't change anything.

Comment: When you reinstall you can reset the root's pswd

Comment: Are you sure? 

I don't want to go through a huge process of re-installing if it's not going to work.

Comment: I have both mySQL and Apache running, but it's phpMyAdmin that I can't log into. I copy-pasted the error message straight from the title, so I think that's the only issue.

Comment: There are many ways to login to Mysql. Try the others wihle not just phpmyadmin. It can help you find whats the problem

Comment: "There are many ways to login to Mysql"

as in? I don't want to spend 3 hours on a wild goose chase and then find out nothing works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server (using XAMPP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130141/1045-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-using-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting? I'm new to this too and I feel like the first time I tried it I was having similar issues. I tried rebooting and u installing and I think that cleared it up.

Comment: rebooting meaning closing XAMPP and opening it again, or do you mean rebooting my internet connection/computer?

Comment: Sorry. Thought it was worth a try.